# elastic beanstalk: Rolling Updates through eclipse SDK

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Does deploying via eclipse on elastic beanstalk with "Rolling updates" enabled on beanstalk work?

I am trying to use eclipse sdk to push out updates i make in a rolling fashion to elastic beanstalk and somehow all my instances are getting updated instantaneously instead of the rolling fashion..

Answer (score 1):

Rolling updates are not supported in beanstalk for app version changes.. They are supported for only env changes..  See the blogs below.. As on today web deployments or version updates cause a brief downtime because beanstalk updates all servers at once..

Following URLs are https urls: I cant add the entire link coz outlook is acting over smart and mod'ing the links

```
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=502158&#502158
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=328344&#328344
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=506438&#506438
```

You can do something like this:
    https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=258782